# Dropbox syntax error

Tags: dropbox

I do not believe dropbox is running.  running dropbox status generates an error.
When I invoke dropbox from a terminal, I am getting an error message

```
~$ dropbox
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 232
    except OSError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For context the rest of that section of the file reads:

```
 with closing(sock) as f:
        yield (0, True)
        while True:
            try:
                chunk = f.read(bufsize)
                progress += len(chunk)
                buf.write(chunk)
                yield (float(progress)/size, True)
                if progress == size:
                    break
            except OSError, e:
                if hasattr(e, 'errno') and e.errno == errno.EAGAIN:
                    # nothing left to read
                    yield (float(progress)/size, False)
                else:
                    raise
```

However I am out of my depth and don't know how to proceed with fixing the problem.

I tried to reinstall dropbox and recieved this message:

```
~$ sudo apt install --reinstall dropbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of dropbox is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
```

Ubuntu Software lists Dropbox in the gui as one of the installed packages.  However when I try to remove it to reinstall, I get an error "Unable to remove Dropbox, no packages to remove"

Ubuntu 20.04

Other information:

---

```
~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP 
ubuntu:GNOME 
~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/dropbox
dropbox: /usr/bin/dropbox 
Python 3.8.10 
Python2 2.7.18 
Python3 3.8.10

~$ apt-cache policy dropbox 
dropbox: Installed: 2015.10.28 
Candidate: 2015.10.28 Version table: *** 2015.10.28 100 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: How Dropbox was installed initially? What is you desktop environment? What do you have for `dpkg -S /usr/bin/dropbox`, `which python; which python2; which python3` ?

Comment: I do not remember all the details of how Dropbox was initially installed, as it has come along with my box upgrades since Ubuntu 12.   I will try to answer as thoroughly as I can:   



~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP

ubuntu:GNOME


~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/dropbox
dropbox: /usr/bin/dropbox



Python 3.8.10

Python2 2.7.18

Python3  3.8.10

Comment: Please also add `apt-cache policy dropbox` to the question.

Comment: ~$ apt-cache policy dropbox
dropbox:
  Installed: 2015.10.28
  Candidate: 2015.10.28
  Version table:
 *** 2015.10.28 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Also copying these results into the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to remove the locally installed `dropbox` package by

```
sudo apt-get remove dropbox
```

and install Nautilus-Dropbox instead by

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```